# How to find child elements in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to find the child elements of "row item" and store them in Ordered Dict form then pass it to Excel.
The HTML and my code given below

```
<div class = "col-md-5 col-sm-5"
    <h3>....</h3>
    <div class = "row item">
       ::before
       <div class = "col-md-6 subtitle"> title</div>
       <div class = "col-md-6 ng-binding"> 1233344</div>
       ::after
     </div>
     <div class = "row item">
       ::before
       <div class = "col-md-6 subtitle"> name</div>
       <div class = "col-md-6 ng-binding"> abc</div>
       ::after
     </div>
```

Similarly I have 23 divs of 'row item' class and I want these values in the form of Ordered dict like

```
 Items_dict = {title:1233344, name:abc}
```

My code :

```
    for rowitem in  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="row item"]'):
                titles = rowitem.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="row item"]/div[1]')
                values = rowitem.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="row item"]/div[2]')

                for title,value in zip(titles,values):
                    items_dict[title] = []
                    if(title.text and value.text):
                        items_dict[title.text].append(value.text)
```

Comment: what is your question and what help you are expecting

Comment: I want the subelements of 'row_item' and store them in Ordered dict format

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code by removing first for loop:

```
titles = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="row item"]/div[1]')
values = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="row item"]/div[2]')
items_dict={};

for title,value in zip(titles,values):
       items_dict[title.get_attribute('text')] = value.get_attribute('text')
```